# Get related Model foreignkey (in addition to the ManyToMany) with prefetch_related(model_SET).all()

Tags: django, django-templates, prefetch

With prefetch_related, I retrieve the list of my different warehouses stock like this :

**Model Product**

[nothing special]

**Model Warehouse**

[nothing special]

**Model SstStock**

```
class SstStock(models.Model):
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Produit)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**views.py**

```
class ProductListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    queryset = Product.objects.prefetch_related('sststock_set').all()
    context_object_name = "produits"
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'products/produits.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(
            *args, **kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Produits'
        return context
```

**Template**

```
{% for produit in produits %}
    {{ produit.sku}}<br>
    {% for sst in produit.sststock_set.all %}
        <span>{{ sst.warehouse.code }} - {{sst.qty}} - {{sst.qty}}</span>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But when I get the information related to the warehouse eg. `sst.warehouse.code` in template, the number of queries explodes. (already 36 queries with a pagination of only 10 products)

Is there a way to add **warehouse** in **prefetch_related** in the view ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects):

```
class ProductListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    queryset = Product.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('sststock_set', SstStock.objects.select_related('warehouse'))
    ))
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when updating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

Comment: Oh ! Really effective ! From 36 to 3 queries. I was on a track trying to use selected_related('warehouse') but this was insufficient.
. But what about  the .all() method displayed on Django doc ? Why don't you use it ?

Comment: @Abpostman1: because it is useless `.all()` makes a copy of the queryset, so this is not necessary. Only to turn a manager into a queryset, so you need to use `.all()` for `.objects`, but not for any operation that returns a `QuerySet`.

Comment: Oh really ! I didn't know that. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I couldn't find the way to proceed with serializer for getting my sststock_set, the only solution by the time was to rebuild the data json in the view.

```
data = list()
        for product in products:
            item = {}
            item['sku'] = product.sku
            item['pk'] = product.pk
            item['famille'] = product.famille.nom
            item['etat'] = product.etat.etat
            # print(product.nom)
            item['mageid'] = product.mageid
            item['adresse'] = product.adresse
            item['fournisseur'] = product.fournisseur.nom
            item['mini'] = product.mini
            item['pua'] = float(product.pua)
            item['pta'] = float(product.pta)
            item['nom'] = product.nom
            item['puv'] = float(product.puv)
            item['ptv'] = float(product.ptv)
            item['cau'] = float(product.cau)
            item['cau_cli'] = float(product.cau_cli)
            item['maxsst2'] = product.maxsst2

            item['sststock'] = list()
            for sst in product.sststock_set.all():
                item['sststock'].append(
                    {'sst_code': sst.warehouse.code, 'sst_id': sst.warehouse.pk, 'qty': sst.qty})
            data.append(item)
        data = json.dumps(data)
        
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```